# A jquery countdown issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am using countdown timer in my project.

I want to make a 30 day counter.

Javascript function is as follows..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            JBCountDown({
                secondsColor : "#ffdc50",
                secondsGlow  : "none",

                minutesColor : "#9cdb7d",
                minutesGlow  : "none",

                hoursColor   : "#378cff",
                hoursGlow    : "none",

                daysColor    : "#ff6565",
                daysGlow     : "none",

                startDate   : "1385722978",
                endDate     : "1388314978",
                now         : "1385722978"
            });
        });
```

This function takes 3 parameters at last..

startDate,endDate and now..

i made a 30 day difference between startDate and endDate..

but confused about how to set current time in seconds..

Comment: What do you mean "set current time"? And what about it are you "confused" about? Did you want to use the current time (and arithmetic on that time, thereafter) rather than a hardcoded UNIX timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be this .

```
var current = new Date();

    var seconds = (+current.getHours() * 60 * 60 + (+current.getMinutes() * 60 + (+current.getSeconds()); 
console.log(seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the `JBCountDown` does, as you have not provided the code...

On first look the times seem off in terms of how it is used in javascript.. (*they should have 3 more digits..*)

To get the current date try  `new Date().getTime()`

And if you want it in the format of your plugin just devide by 1000, so `new Date().getTime()/1000`

---

If you want to set the `now` parameter then try `now : parseInt(new Date().getTime(),10)`